# WCF, out of memory exception while serializing huge amount of data

Tags: wcf, serialization, deserialization, out-of-memory

Basically, I am fetching data from SQL Server. If I select all data (which is about 80000 rows), then I am getting the following error  (Receiving 100 rows is working fine)

```
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. <br/>

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. <br/>

Exception Details: System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Stack Trace: 

[OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.]
   System.Text.StringBuilder.ToString() +29
   System.IO.StringWriter.ToString() +14
   System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(String value) +110
   System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder.HtmlEncode(String value) +54
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.set_InnerText(String value) +24
   PerformanceCompare._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\KK33562\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestWebService\PerformanceCompare\Default.aspx.cs:34
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

Web.config (Client Side)

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="endpointbehaviour">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:50:00"
      openTimeout="00:50:00" receiveTimeout="00:50:00" sendTimeout="00:50:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:53268/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="WCFService.IService1"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" behaviorConfiguration="endpointbehaviour" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Web.config (Server-Side)

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>      
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="TestWCF.Service1Behavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
  <services>
    <service name="TestWCF.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="TestWCF.Service1Behavior">
      <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="TestWCF.IService1" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
  </services>    
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" openTimeout="00:50:00" closeTimeout="00:50:00" sendTimeout="00:50:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward: "The exception that is thrown when there is not enough memory to continue the execution of a program" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception.aspx

Comment: @DaveZiegler Thank you for your response!. I understand that I have a problem with memory management thing. My question is that how can I resolve that issue..

Comment: Well, how much data are you returning? How much memory is available? I don't think this is something you can fix in web.config. Can you bring back less data or do you need all 80000+ rows at once?

Comment: Unless you are only accessing this over a fast local network, you'd have to think performance would be another reason that you shouldn't try to return all that data at once.

Comment: So, there is no way that I can return 80000+ rows at once? Should I break down my code to call several times? I have no idea about the memory management....

Comment: Since we don't know much about what it is you're doing, it will be hard to make design decisions for you. Should you break it into multiple calls? Possibly, seems like something worth trying since you know 100 works and 80000 doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're returning 80K rows from your service then I think you'd better get rid of the service all together. Just get the client to access the DB directly and then they can pull all the rows they need from the DB.

**EDIT**

Introducing a service boundary where it's not necessary is a very common error, and one I see happening more and more. It would be cleaner in most cases to have the client call the database directly using NHibernate or even ADO and a stored proc or view.

If your client can't physically see the database on the network then you may have to use a service.

Comment: thank you for your response! Could you please kindly provide some example? I am confused about the meaning of "get rid of the service all together. Just get the client to access the DB directly"... I want to keep my client-side clean..